# Isomorphism on tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know how to show that if I have 2 vectorial spaces V and W that $Hom(V, W) \simeq V^* \otimes W$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only valid when $W$ is finite-dimensional. In this case one
can prove it by writing $W=F^n=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n F$, where $F$ is the field in question, and
using the natural isomorphism
$$\text{Hom}\left(V,\bigoplus_{i=1}^n W_i\right)
\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\text{Hom}(V,W_i).$$

Comment: $\text{Hom}\left(V,\bigoplus_{i=1}^n F\right)
\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\text{Hom}(V,F) \simeq V^* \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n-1} Hom(V,F)$ right ? But how do you get $W$?

Comment: Actually it's valid if either $V$ or $W$ is finite-dimensional. In general, $V^{\ast} \otimes W$ is exactly the subspace of $\text{Hom}(V, W)$ consisting of maps $V \to W$ with finite rank.